# Ubuntu 17.10: change keyboard delay

Tags: keyboard, 17.10

How to set the keyboard's autorepeat delay with stock Ubuntu 17.10? It feels to sluggish by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Settings>Universal Access, select "Repeat Keys" under "Typing" header:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Arg! I was searching under Devices > Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**For me it worked like this:**

Open terminal and edit this file:

**`$ sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`**

Find the setting "enable-deferred-volume", remove the semicolon at the start of the line if is commented out and set its value to "no"

**`enable-deferred-volume = no`**

Reboot the system.

_

See more:

https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Delay-when-changing-volume/td-p/1589346